# rsync failing to choose the correct target directory

Tags: debian, rsync

I'm trying to write a short shell script which also handles copying a file called `webcam.jpg` into a date coded subdirectory. I'm using rsync for this as it automatically creates a directory if it doesn't already exist.

Everything works fine when I use:

```
rsync -a webcam.jpg ./$(date +%Y-%m-%d)/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M).jpg
```

But when going one directory deeper, rsync starts throwing errors, and I really don't have a clue why. I'm typing:

```
rsync -a webcam.jpg ./saved_images/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M).jpg
```

and my output is:

```
rsync: change_dir#3 "/var/www/tmp/test//./saved_images/2013-07-07" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(677) [Receiver=3.0.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (9 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]
```

I see the relevant error in the first line, but why is rsync trying to access this `test//./saved_images` directory in the first place? What's wrong with `test/saved_images/`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok `/var/www/tmp/test//./saved_images/2013-07-07` is the same as `/var/www/tmp/test/saved_images/2013-07-07`.

Double `/` are ignored you can type `ls ////` and it is the same as `ls /`.

The dot `.` is the same directory it is in.
So `ls /.` shows the same output as `ls /` and so `/var/www/tmp/test/.` points to the directory `/var/www/tmp/test/`.

So `rsync` just takes the current directory it is in, in you case `var/www/tmp/test/` (at least when your path starts with a `.`). 
Then its adds an extra `/` so it can make sure that the path it definitely has a `/` add the end.
In the last step its adds the part you gave it, here `./saved_images/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M).jpg`

The error you are seeing is that the directory `/var/www/tmp/test/saved_images/` is not there and `rsync` will not create it, because it seams that `rsync` only creates one directory.

### Edit

Maybe for your problem you should just use a script with

```
today_dir=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
mkdir -p ./$today_dir/
cp webcam.jpg ./$today_dir/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M).jpg
```

Comment: Oddly enough I get the same error when saved_images exists, but not when the relevant subdirectory (2013-07-07) also exists inside it. My conclusion is therefore that rsync is only ever able to create the first directory in the tree of the target. Is that correct? And if so, what would the best course of action in my case be? Multiple rsyncs seems somewhat ridiculous.

Interestingly enough I get the same error when calling rsync from inside saved_images and trying to get ../webcam.jpg

Comment: The problem seems to be that you are also trying to rename the file

Comment: Unfortunately this makes rsync a lot less attractive, but thank you for the hint in your edit! Finished off my script with this and everything is working as I expected it to.